# Get Objective-C Value in C wrapper (Unity Plugin)

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, unity-game-engine

I'm not familiar with Objecticve-C. I'm using it because I want to natively/correctly check if an app is installed on ios. I found the Objective-C snippet to see if an app is installed and understand needing a C-wrapper to basically have unity talk to the Objective-C script (mm file). Just don't understand how to get the C-wrapper to get the Objective-C value I have within my mm script.

```
// UnityPluginTest-1.mm
//
// Created by OJ on 7/13/16.
//
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>  
@interface SampleClass:NSObject
/* method declaration */
- (BOOL)isFBInstalledX;
@end

@implementation SampleClass

//Objective-C value I want      
- (BOOL)isFBInstalledX {
return [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://"]];
}

@end

//C-wrapper that talks to Unity
extern "C"
{
bool isFBInstalled(){

// Need to get the Objective C BOOL value from above, my c# script will get this value once retrieved


//return -(Bool) isFBInstalledX value  //--this doesn't work
//return ..... // I give up  :(

}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the Answer! - [Objective-C to UnityPlugin - App Installed Status](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1217507/get-objective-c-functionvalue-in-c-wrapper-for-uni.html#answer-1218701)